# AndroidStudio ndkBuild: How to include flavor jni folders?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors, ndk-build

I am upgrading my project from experimentalNdk to ndkBuild

I have copied one of the previously generated Android.mk from `build/intermediates/ndk/green/debug/Android.mk` to my main jni folder.

I kept most of it but the following three includes, as they are flavor/buildType specific: (assuming productFlavor is "green")

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += C:\path\to\project\modulename\src\green\jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += C:\path\to\project\modulename\src\debug\jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += C:\path\to\project\modulename\src\greenDebug\jni
```

I managed to add two of those lines via gradle:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/Android.mk"
    }
}

productFlavors {
    green {
         externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {                    
                arguments "LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=$projectDir\src\green\jni"           
            }
        }
    }

    ... Other flavors ...
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {                    
                arguments "LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=$projectDir\src\debug\jni"           
            }
        }
    }

    ... Other build types ...
}
```

But where can I add the third line, that combines both?

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=$projectDir\src\greenDebug\jni
```